# Android BLE ScanFilter

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to filter BLE packets while scanning only by the manufacturer ID as defined in Bluetooth SIG spec. For example, I am trying to filter packets sent by Intel Corp. manufacturer ID which is 0x002, 2.

On http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.Builder.html#setManufacturerData(int, byte[], byte[]) it is mentioned that the first two bytes are reserved for the manID, so assume I would like to send one addition byte with random value, how should I set the byte data and mask?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this should be run and try thing. What have you tried, what are the observation?